# Using Parallel.Foreach Inside A Thread

Tags: c#, .net, linq, task-parallel-library

I have a thread that loads data when a service is starting. I call a method in this thread that uses Parallel.Foreach to iterate a set of data. But the linq query that I have inside the parallel forerach, gets a objet reference not set to an instance error.

***The same logic works if I remove the Parallel.Foreach though or if I remove the thread.** **Even locking the list doesnt help.***

```
    loadingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PreloadData));
                loadingThread.IsBackground = true;
                loadingThread.Start();
---------------------------------------

    public static void PreloadData()
    {
     Parallel.ForEach(loadedIDs.Keys, indexDefId =>
                    {
                        List<FixingEvent> lst = null;
                        lock (loadedEvents)
                        {
                            lst = (from e in loadedEvents where e.DIVACode.Equals(indexDefId) select e).ToList();
                        }

---------------------------
    }
```

I get an exception in the linq query inside - ' **e is null and hence object reference error'**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `loadedEvents` being set in your code? That variable is null and is the culprit, need more info on it.

Comment: It is prepopulated even before the thread is started. I double checked this and it is fully populated and has no null values. In fact, same code runs fine if I dont call it from a thread.

Comment: Do you call it in exactly the same place in the code when you start it outside the thread?

Comment: What is the type of loadedEvents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the list loadedEvents contains null elements. Maybe due to a race condition.

Comment: I accept this as answer because if I check null conditions somehow it works fine. But still, am not sure why this works without any null checks if I just run it without a separate thread. I also suspect some race condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should not lock the `loadedEvents` object. According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private
>   static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

you do not need to lock the object you are accessing - you simply need an object to lock on.

Comment: thanks for the tip. But unfortunately, the problem is not that. Somehow I get an null reference error when I call the parallel.foreach in a thread.